# Does MarkLogic have built-in XQuery crypto functions to create XML signature and verify signed XML?

Tags: cryptography, xquery, marklogic

I have a use case to create XML signatures and verify signed XML. I imagine such functionality is present in MarkLogic (e.g. for various security features) but I don't if it is available as XQuery modules to developers. Thank you!

Comment: You might get a more specific answer, pointing to specific functions if you indicated what hashing algorithms you plan on using.

Comment: Hi @MadsHansen, I am not an expert on this topic. The algorithms and other processing steps (XML canonicalization) are discussed in this W3C standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/

Answer (score 1):

For a bit more information on hunterhacker's second answer: as of about two or three years ago, a group I was working with built a SAML handler on a server that had both Node and MarkLogic components. We'd been able to get other NPM packages working in MarkLogic, but couldn't get `xml-crypt`o functional well enough and ended up having to rely on a process that did the decryption work in Node and did the database writes in MarkLogic. We didn't see anything in the ML10 major release that seemed like it'd bridge the gap we needed for `xml-crypto` to work, so we'd found that the easiest way was to leave it with `saml2js` on the Node side and a few internal requests.

If your project has code in any other language, it may be worth looking into implementing the crypto work on that side.

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of XQuery extension functions documented at https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp/extension including several for hashes, which may help you.

If you don't find what you're looking for, you can run JavaScript natively in MarkLogic and even call the JS from XQuery, and vice versa.